# Can you restrict viewing access for revenue in Firebase Analytics Dashboard?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

Firebase Analytics dashboard has a category that reports the Apps revenue: "How much revenue is your app making?"

Can you prevent dashboard users to see this category?
If not, can you maybe prevent just the Analytics dashboard, but still let a developer user have access to the rest of the features?

I've searched the Firebase roles and permissions, but couldn't find anything that could just prevent the revenue from being seen and also, the Develop role seems to give access to all Analytics statistics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope -- right now, the permissions aren't that granular. It's a good feature request, though. I'll raise it with the team.

Comment: Hey Todd  any news?

Comment: I'm also wondering about this, it would be super useful to have this feature!

Comment: I'm still looking for that

Comment: Any news about that?

Comment: Seriously? Why do I want my workers to know my revenue? It is Business 101. At least, giving editor Firebase role without google analytics?

Comment: More than 4 years has passed :)

Comment: In this case, Firebase crashlytics is not useful for us, it is very disappointing that this feature is missing.